# Strange wifi in Kali Linux

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router

I have installed Kali Linux on my Dell Inspiron N5110 Laptop. during the installation process I have manually set up the network settings (autoconfiguration failed). I have set up the ip as 192.168.1.2, netmask 255.255.255.0 and the other two settings were 192.168.1.1 (my home router IP). After installation I have connected to my network and didn't get any error.warning, nothing, but I couldn't load any page. Also the chat program and apt-get were down. I have then connected to a neighbor network and everything worked fine. I have tried today to connect to my work router and it didn't work either, but everithing is ok if I connect to my neighbor network.

I am new to linux, so please tell me what should I do to be able to connect to my own router via wifi.

In case this helps, my home router has WPA encryption and my work router has WEP protection. My neighbor's network is unprotected. I now remember that the IP that my home router gave me when I was using Windows was 192.168.1.101.

thank you in advance

Comment: Post your `ifconfig` output as well as your `lspci`. In this way we can see how your network devices are configurated and which one you have in your PC.

Answer (score 0):

I know when I used Mac changer after I have connected to a network i have used in the past it would not work for me I had to remove the network re-add it under the new fake Mac. And then again whenever I changed the Mac. You try removing and readding?